# Why is FloodFill algorithm exceeding Leetcode's maximum recursion limit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, depth-first-search

I am working on the floodfill algorithm using the same logic as the very popular *Number of Islands* problem. So this solution worked when I ran the code with the sample input, but once I submit, it says `Recursion Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.

How can I do this better? It looks fine to me but I know something is wrong.

```
def floodfill(grid,sr,sc,newColor):
    og= grid[sr][sc]

    recurse(grid,sr,sc,newColor,og)
    return grid




def recurse(grid,sr,sc,newColor,og):
    if grid[sr][sc]!= og:
        return


    grid[sr][sc] = newColor
    if sr !=0:
        recurse(grid,sr-1,sc,newColor,og)

    if sc !=0:
        recurse(grid,sr,sc-1,newColor,og)

    if sc != len(grid[0])-1:
        recurse(grid,sr,sc+1,newColor,og)

    if sr != len(grid)-1:
        recurse(grid,sr+1,sc,newColor,og)


floodfill([[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,1]],1,1,2)
```

Comment: Is your base case correct? Have you tried printing anything to see what is happening? Maybe get familiar with [The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) and step through it to see what is happening? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: I am using Python Tutor to step through the code. It's working there.

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Alternative implementations are described in the Wikipedia article on [floodfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). As one example, to avoid a function recursion error the code could create its own explicit stack instead of using the Python interpreter's execution stack.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your example works for me. Add `print(sr,sc,newColor,og); print(f'{pprint(grid,width=20)}'); print('*****')` to the beginning of `recurse` (import pprint of course).

Comment: @wwii I added a return in floodfill before it hit recursion. It needed the edge case if the new color equaled the old color. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the code is fine for the case where newColor != og. But my guess is that you are seeing your error because in the case of newColor == og, the stopping condition

```
if grid[sr][sc]!= og:
        return
```

Will never occur, causing `recurse` to endlessly recurse. This can be fixed by just adding a check in your `floodfill` method for this edge case.

Comment: Awesome, this worked thank you. I did a return of the grid if it equals og.